# Use unknown values as selectors in Less

Tags: css, less

Given this markup:

```
<div class="parent" data-active="typeA">
    <div class="child" data-show="typeA">Show only when parent=typeA</div>
    <div class="child" data-show="typeB">Show only when parent=typeB</div>
    <div class="child" data-show="typeC">Show only when parent=typeC</div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to write a globally applicable LESS rule that only displays a child when its `data-show` attribute matches the parent's `data-active` attribute.

Something like this:

```
.parent {
    .child { display:none; }
    &[data-active="?"] .child[data-show="?"] { display:block; }
}
```

...where `?` should not be a fixed value, but a condition that applies no matter the value, as long as they are the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think the generic approach is possible and also I think it's not a good idea having this in the css. 
On the other hand, with sass you could generate all the necessary rules with the help of a map.

Comment: not possible with CSS (and thus, not possible with anything that compiles into CSS).

Comment: are you open to a JS solution?

Comment: @andi I'm trying to avoid JS - it would be easy to do, but I want to keep this in the CSS. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2):

As LESS gets compiled to CSS and there is no generic approach for doing this in CSS, I only come up with a solution that requires you to know every possible *type*.

```
.parent {
    .child { display: none; }     
    &[data-active="typeA"] {
        .child[data-show="typeA"] { display: block; }
    }
    &[data-active="typeB"] {
        .child[data-show="typeB"] { display: block; }
    }
    &[data-active="typeC"] {
        .child[data-show="typeC"] { display: block; }
    }
}
```

Depending on your preferences and to avoid redundancy you could also define a function for adding the different types.

```
.parent {
    .child { display: none; }
    .addType("typeA");
    .addType("typeB");
    .addType("typeC");    
}

.addType(@type) {
    &[data-active="@{type}"] {
        .child[data-show="@{type}"] { display: block; }
    }
}
```

And if you want to make this even more generic, you could define an array of types and call `.addType` for each of the types like this:

```
@types: "typeA", "typeB", "typeC";

.parent {
    .child { display: none; }
    .-(@i: length(@types)) when (@i > 0) {
        @type: extract(@types, @i);
        .addType(@type);
        .-((@i - 1));
    } .-;
}

.addType(@type) { /* see above */ }
```